Do Extreme Switches need to have ports filled in sequence
I'm having a weird issue with a network switch that I'm trying to determine if it's an actually defective switch. I have an Extreme Branded Switch deployed (ISW8GbP, 4-SPF) with ports 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6 occupied with similar devices. All 5 devices are receiving POE, however, port 6 is not being detected, and ports 3 and 5 are being detected in a restart but fail after a period.
When I moved port 6 to port 4, so that everything is now in sequence, everything starts working. I've tried new patch cables in port 6, re-configuring the switch, etc. so I'm now leaning towards a defective switch, but I wanted to check if there is any requirement to fill each port in order. I couldn't find anything in the documentation, hence I'm turn to Stack Overflow.

Can't imagine that in-sequence population should be necessary. What do the logs say when something is plugged or when a port fails? Does the same happen with non-PDs? Perhaps the configuration is weird and you could show that to us (in text format, using the editor's {} preformat option).

Switch ports can occasionally fail due to hardware issues. The fact that port 6 isn’t detected at all and that ports 3 and 5 only work temporarily could point to failing hardware, especially since moving the connection from port 6 to port 4 restored functionality.

In general, no, each port is functionally independent.
However, hardware design is a factor. Most switches use multiport chips, and multiport buffers. For example:

ports 1-4 are driven by a single PHY chip
ports 1-8 shared an 8MB buffer
ports 1-24 connect to the same SoC
ports 1-6 share a PoE supply

So, misbehaving hardware can span more than one port.
